# Removing element from table - react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I'm trying to create a CRUD application in react, and I have encountered several problems.
How can I remove an item from the table?
Is it possible to pass id to Info component in render method? How can I later link it to the  element?
Why does the e.PreventDefault () method cause an error when I try to delete?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const Info = ({ index, login, pass }) => (
    <>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>LOGIN</th>
                <th>PASSWORD</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td key={index}>{index}{alert(index)}</td>
                <td>{login}</td>
                <td>{pass}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <input type="submit" value='X' onClick={() => this.del(index)}></input>
    </>
);

class List extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: [],
            login: "",
            pass: "",
        };

        this.add = this.add.bind(this);
        this.show = this.show.bind(this);
        this.del = this.show.bind(this);
    }



    add(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
        });
    }

    show(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (!this.state.login.length || !this.state.pass.length) {
            return;
        }

        else {
            const newUser = {
                login: this.state.login,
                pass: this.state.pass,
            };

            this.setState(state => ({
                data: state.data.concat(newUser),
            }))
        }
    }

    del(index) {

        const tab = this.state.data.filter((temp) => temp.index !== index);
        this.setState(({
            data: tab
        }));

    }
    render() {



        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.show}>
                    <label>Login</label><br></br><input type='text' name='login' onChange={e => this.add(e)}></input><br></br>
                    <label>Password</label><br></br><input type='text' name='pass' onChange={e => this.add(e)}></input><br></br>
                    <input type="submit" value="Add"></input>
                </form>
                <table>

                    {this.state.data.map((val, index) => (
                        <>
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>ID</th>
                                    <th>LOGIN</th>
                                    <th>PASSWORD</th>

                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td key={index}>{index}</td>
                                    <td>{val.login}</td>
                                    <td>{val.pass}</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                            <input type="submit" value='X' onClick={() => this.del(index)}></input>
                        </>
                    ))}
                </table>
            </div>
        )
    }
}


export default List;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are small corrections in your code.

1. `this.del = this.show.bind(this);` should be `this.del = this.del.bind(this);`
2. You are trying to remove the element from the state data using index (`this.state.data.filter((temp) => temp.index !== index);`) but the element inside the data doesn't have an index property.

In that case, you can use `splice` to delete the element from the data.

```js
class List extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: [],
            login: "",
            pass: "",
        };

        this.add = this.add.bind(this);
        this.show = this.show.bind(this);
        this.del = this.del.bind(this);
    }



    add(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
        });
    }

    show(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (!this.state.login.length || !this.state.pass.length) {
            return;
        }

        else {
            const newUser = {
                login: this.state.login,
                pass: this.state.pass,
            };

            this.setState(state => ({
                data: state.data.concat(newUser),
            }))
        }
    }

    del(index) {
let {data}=this.state
        data.splice(index, 1);
        this.setState(({
            data
        }));

    }
    render() {



        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.show}>
                    <label>Login</label><br></br><input type='text' name='login' onChange={e => this.add(e)}></input><br></br>
                    <label>Password</label><br></br><input type='text' name='pass' onChange={e => this.add(e)}></input><br></br>
                    <input type="submit" value="Add"></input>
                </form>
                <table>

                    {this.state.data.map((val, index) => (
                        <React.Fragment>
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>ID</th>
                                    <th>LOGIN</th>
                                    <th>PASSWORD</th>

                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td key={index}>{index}</td>
                                    <td>{val.login}</td>
                                    <td>{val.pass}</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                            <input type="submit" value='X' onClick={() => this.del(index)}></input>
                        </React.Fragment>
                    ))}
                </table>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<List />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

Here is the demo [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xf7q32b4/1/)

Hope it helps :)